# kops validate cluster fails with even after providing appropriate state and clustername

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, kops

I am trying to run validate cluster command as per the documentation [kops validate](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_validate/)

Strangely it fails with following error

```bash
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my_legit_key> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my_legit_secret_key> kops validate cluster --wait 10m --state="s3://<my_bucket_name>" --name=<my_cluster_name>
Validating cluster <my_cluster_name>


Validation failed: cannot load kubecfg settings for "<my_cluster_name>": context "<my_cluster_name>" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the `kubeconfig` before and the error disappeared.

```bash
$ export KUBECONFIG=~/workspace/myrepo/_kube/dev/kubeconfig
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my_legit_key> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my_legit_secret_key> kops validate cluster --wait 10m --state="s3://<my_bucket_name>" --name=<my_cluster_name>
## And it worked
```

If the kubeconfig does not exist yet, then we can export it as well.

```bash
$ kops export kubecfg --admin=87600h0m0s --kubeconfig ~/workspace/myrepo/_kube/dev/kubeconfig --state=s3://my-kops-dev-v4 --name=k8.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the [`kops get`](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cli/kops_get/) command to see if kOps can read the configuration stored in the s3 bucket correctly. If you get an error then you probably have missed a required configuration in your environment. I had a similar issue but I was using [Named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) for AWS. I had to set an extra variable `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` for kOps to pick up the settings (I think it was AWS_REGION) correctly. If it's just `kops validate` that is failing then make sure you are using the correct context.

Comment: Actually its able to read S3 configuration. What its not able to do is load the kubeconfig. What really helped me is loading the kubeconfig earlier.